# So I am working on a .csv file and found that in given data, things are not quite formatted as they should be

Tags: python, data-mining, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I want to clean data in such a way that if a row exceeds certain columns, it shall be deleted

[image]

Comment: Please edit the code of your attempt to solve this problem into your question, and a snippet of data, and perhaps someone will be able to help you fix it. Without your code, it might appear like you think StackOverflow is a code-writing service, which it isn’t.

Answer (score 0):

Below code may help.

```py
number_of_column=3
with open("test.csv","r") as f:
    with open("out.csv","w") as f1:
        line=f.readline()
        while line:
            if len(line.split(","))<=number_of_column:
                f1.write(line)
            line=f.readline()
```